# Radio button clicked twice in row return error

Tags: radio-button, tcl

I am using 5 radio buttons which when invoked it creates new widgets that are specific to each button.  However, once widgets are created you cannot have the same widget created with the same path name or an error is displayed.  The radio buttons are able to be clicked more than once which creates the error mentioned before.  Is there anyway to either restrict pressing the same radio button twice in a row or keep the window from trying to be recreated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `[winfo exists]`. something like this:

```
radiobutton .r1 -text 1 -value 1 -variable radiovalue -command make_widget
radiobutton .r2 -text 2 -value 2 -variable radiovalue -command make_widget
pack .r1 .r2
proc make_widget {} {
    global radiovalue
    set name .widget_$radiovalue
    if {[winfo exists $name]} {
        puts "$name already exists"
    } else {
        pack [label $name -text $name]
    }
}
```

Comment: I will give this a try.  Is winfo short for window information?  Can I also use that command to hide widgets?

Comment: [winfo man page](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/winfo.htm). you hide widgets with [wm withdraw](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/wm.htm) or [pack forget](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/pack.htm) (or "grid forget" or "place forget")

Answer (score 0):

You could disable the radio button that is pressed until another is pressed or you could delete the existing set of widgets if any before creating any.

Comment: How do I reference that specific radio button?  Since they are part of the same group all of them have the same variable name but a different value.  would I do something liek this: radio[1] configure -state disable?

Comment: I think that you index them by the value or the text but as I am not a regular tcl user I am not sure.